# Azure ARM can't create hostingEnvironments : 'Location has an invalid value'

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm not able to create a "HostingEnvironments" in a ARM template.
I usually use

```
"location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
```

but it seems not working for a resource of type "HostingEnvironments"

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
    "name": "[variables('hostingEnvironment').name]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('vnet').name, '/subnets/', variables('vnet').subnet.name)]"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "Name": "[variables('hostingEnvironment').name]",
      "ipSslAddressCount": "[variables('hostingEnvironment').ipSslAddressCount]",
      "workerPools": [
        {
          "workerSizeId": 0,
          "workerSize": "medium",
          "workerCount": 1
        }
      ],
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "MultiSize": "medium",
      "MultiRoleCount": "1",
      "VNETName": "[variables('vnet').name]",
      "VNetResourceGroupName": "[resourceGroup().name]",
      "VNETSubnetName": "[variables('vnet').subnet.name]"
    }
  }
```

Here the full template https://github.com/toto-castaldi/azure-templates/blob/master/serviceApp/template.json

If I insert cabled string "West Europe" the resource is created.

Comment: hm, for me it doesn't work even with the value hardcoded

Comment: also, what are you trying to achieve, you can link to a vnet without gateway, and where did you find `Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments` is that an alias for `serverFarms`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you are deploying your WebApp with App Service Environment via Azure ARM template. Based on your template, I have tested it on my side and I could reproduce this issue.

I found a [issue](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/thewindowsazureproductsite/create_an_app_service_environment/) about creating an App Service Environment, and as [Stefan Schackow](https://disqus.com/by/stefsch/) who is the Principal Program Manager Lead of Azure Web Sites commented as follows:

> Just in case anyone runs into this - **we uncovered a bug where the App Service management infrastructure isn't correctly handling the normalized location string returned from the resourceGroup.Location() call**. For now, the workaround is as mentioned above - grab the March 21st version of the templates and explicitly provide a string for "location" in the azuredeploy.parameters.json file.

For now, the workaround is that you need to explicitly provide a string for "location" in the azuredeploy.parameters.json file. I would report this issue, also you could add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager).

Comment: Your assumptions are correct : I am deploying a WebApp with App Service Environment via Azure ARM template.
So it's a MS Issue. I'll use the workaround.

Comment: Has anyone found a proper solution to this?

Comment: No and it appears to still be the same. I'm getting this error today.

Comment: I am still getting this error message too. This is absolutely ridiculous that it has not been fixed by now!