# resourceGroup().location is not taking in Logic Apps ARM deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-logic-apps

I am getting below error while trying to deploy logic App using ARM template in Azure DevOps

```
There were errors in your deployment. Error code: InvalidResourceLocation.
##[error]The specified location '[resourceGroup().location]' is invalid. A location must consist of characters, whitespace, digit, or following symbols '(,)'.
```

I have below sample in Parameter files

```
"parameters": {
    "logicAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "LAKeyVaultConnection",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Logic App."
      }
    },
    "logicAppLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location of the Logic App."
      }
    }
```

Is there anything wrong in Param files ?

Comment: I think you can only use `resourceGroup().location` as default value for parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas , it looks like only variables section is able to parse this not Parameter.

Comment: it wont wok in parameter file. but it will work if it s the default value of your parameter `"defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"`

Comment: Hi @Thomas , yes you are correct. Its taking resourceGroup.Location when its in defaultValue.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-test-cases#location-uses-parameter)  it says,

> Below is the sample code that passes when we use it in the main template. Here we are creating a parameter where resource group locations is taken as a default and also it allows users to give a different value.

```
{  
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",  
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",  
"parameters": {  
"location": {  
"type": "string",  
"defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",  
"metadata": {  
"description": "Location for the resources."  
}  
}  
},  
"variables": {},  
"resources": [  
{  
"type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",  
"apiVersion": "2021-02-01",  
"name": "storageaccount1",  
"location": "[parameters('location')]",  
"kind": "StorageV2",  
"sku": {  
"name": "Premium_LRS",  
"tier": "Premium"  
}  
}  
],  
"outputs": {}
```

The template is taken as a reference from above Microsoft Documentation.
For further refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490728/azure-arm-cant-create-hostingenvironments-location-has-an-invalid-value)  for more information.

Comment: I have set in same way in both template & Parameters file but looks like at deployment its failing. But when passing as resourceGroup().location in variables it working. Might be some limitation.